# How to destructuring a prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting a linter error within my react project regarding **destructuring assignment of props, state, and context**. The link is [here](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/destructuring-assignment.md).

I don't understand how I'm supposed to destructure this element.

```
const { job_id } = props.match.params.job_id;
```

Comment: `const { job_id } = props.match.params`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably just

```
const { job_id } = props.match.params;
```

Check out the JavaScript [object destructuring documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) for more details.

```js
const o = {id: '5', name: 'Jon'};
const { id } = o;

console.log(id);
```

If you need to assign it to a new variable name, you can do this too:

```js
const o = {id: '5', name: 'Jon'};
const { id: alternative } = o;

console.log(alternative);
```

Answer (score 2):

On the right hand side of destructuring assignment there should be the object from which you want to get property.

```
const { job_id } = props.match.params;
```

Consider the an object with property `prop` and `prop2`.

```js
const obj = { prop: "something", prop2:"string of prop2" }
const { prop } = obj; //get the prop key of the variable 'obj'

console.log(prop); //something

const { prop2 } = obj.prop2 //get the property 'prop2' from the string "string of prop2" which is undefined.

console.log(prop2) //undefined
```